# Xamarin android proguard ends up with error - the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, proguard

My release build of a `Xamarin.Android` project with `proguard` enabled ends up with plenty of exceptions.following is a shred of my diagnose log :

> PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
>   1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
>   1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
>   1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
>   1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
>   1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper$RequestPropertiesCallback: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
>   1>  Note: android.support.v7.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find dynamically referenced class android.graphics.Insets
>   1>  Note: com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzad: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl
>   1>  Note: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.DowngradeableSafeParcel accesses a field 'NULL' dynamically
>   1>        Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable { java.lang.String NULL; }'
>   1>        Maybe this is library field 'android.util.JsonToken { android.util.JsonToken NULL; }'
>   1>        Maybe this is library field 'java.sql.Types { int NULL; }'
>   1>        Maybe this is library field 'org.json.JSONObject { java.lang.Object NULL; }'
>   1>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
>   1>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
>   1>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep'
>   1>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep'
>   1>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep'
>   1>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep'
>   1>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.support.annotation.Keep'
>   1>  Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'sun.misc.Unsafe'
>   1>  Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder { DataHolder(com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder$zza,int,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder$zza'
>   1>  Note: there were 8 references to unknown classes.
>   1>        You should check your configuration for typos.
>   1>  Note: there were 1 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
>   1>        You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
>   1>        (using '-keep').
>   1>  Note: there were 2 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
>   1>        You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
>   1>  Note: there were 1 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
>   1>        You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
>   1>        (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
>   1>PROGUARD : warning : there were 6 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>   1>           You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
>   1>  java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   1>      at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
>   1>      at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
>   1>      at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
>   1>      at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
>   1>  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

I searched a lot to find a rule to fix `android.support.annotation.Keep` warning but no luck.any idea how to get it right?

Comment: You seem to use 3rd party library urlimageviewhelper. Could you correctly share the url of the same. Is it https://components.xamarin.com/view/urlimageviewhelper ??

Comment: @sJy tnx for your comment. you are exactly right `android.support.annotation.Keep` was not an issue at all.i just solved the issue by adding a `keep` rule as  `-keep public class com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.**` and it works now.